# Invalid Java Regex for JSON

Tags: java, json, regex

For some reason this regex keeps saying it is invalid in java, but on the online testers it works fine:

```
({.+?})
```

I am using it for a JSON data structure.

Is there a way to get it to work with Java?

Included link: http://regexr.com/3bs0p

Comment: Why are you parsing JSON with regex?

Comment: using a tool that requires it, i know its not the best idea but i'm doing small POC.

Comment: What error you are getting when you try to use this regex? Also do you know that `{` and `}` are special characters which can be used like `[a-z]{n}` to find `n` characters in range `a-z`?

Comment: "Not a Valid Java Regular Expression".  When I use it on this online tool i get errors as well: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com

Comment: Put that error message into your question and provide simple code example which will let us reproduce it. BTW you can test if your string represent valid regex by using `Pattern.compile(regex)`. If there are any problems with your regex you should be informed about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my 2 cents:

1. You need to escape the opening `{` in Java regex to tell the engine it is not the brace starting the [*limiting quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit).
2. Do not use regexr.com to test Java regexps, use [OCPSoft Visual Regex Tester](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/) or [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) that support Java regex syntax.
3. Do not use round brackets around the whole pattern, you can always refer to it with `.group(0)` or `$0` back-reference.

The regex should look like

```
String pattern = "\\{.+?}"; // Note that `.+?` requires at least 1 character,
                            // Use .*? to allow 0 characters
```

And

4. **Do not parse JSON with regex**. See [*How to parse JSON in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to escape your { } with backslashes, since you are treating them as literal characters.

E.g.

```
(\\{.+?\\})
```